MAX98357A creating popping noise/Understanding I2S for STM32
I'm trying to learn I2S on STM32. In this case I'm using the MAX98357A I2S amplifier breakout board from Adafruit, a NUCLEOF411RE, and an 8 ohm speaker
I found an example for I2S in general and I'm getting some results from it (very quiet audio, almost can't hear it but I can feel the speaker buzzing in my hand and hear a bit of a tone when I hold it up to my ear), but there's some problems. I have a few guesses, but they're just guesses at the moment. Below is the example with my I2S setup.
/* USER CODE BEGIN Header */
/**
  ******************************************************************************
  * @file           : main.c
  * @brief          : Main program body
  ******************************************************************************
  * @attention
  *
  * Copyright (c) 2024 STMicroelectronics.
  * All rights reserved.
  *
  * This software is licensed under terms that can be found in the LICENSE file
  * in the root directory of this software component.
  * If no LICENSE file comes with this software, it is provided AS-IS.
  *
  ******************************************************************************
  */
/* USER CODE END Header */
/* Includes ------------------------------------------------------------------*/
#include "main.h"
#include "stm32f4xx_hal.h"
/* Private includes ----------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN Includes */
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
/* USER CODE END Includes */

/* Private typedef -----------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PTD */

/* USER CODE END PTD */

/* Private define ------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PD */
#define PI 3.14159265358979323846
#define TAU (2.0 * PI)
/* USER CODE END PD */

/* Private macro -------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PM */

/* USER CODE END PM */

/* Private variables ---------------------------------------------------------*/
I2S_HandleTypeDef hi2s2;
DMA_HandleTypeDef hdma_spi2_tx;

UART_HandleTypeDef huart2;

/* USER CODE BEGIN PV */

/* USER CODE END PV */

/* Private function prototypes -----------------------------------------------*/
void SystemClock_Config(void);
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void);
static void MX_USART2_UART_Init(void);
static void MX_DMA_Init(void);
static void MX_I2S2_Init(void);
/* USER CODE BEGIN PFP */

/* USER CODE END PFP */

/* Private user code ---------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN 0 */
void UART_Printf(const char* fmt, ...) {
    char buff[256];
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, fmt);
    vsnprintf(buff, sizeof(buff), fmt, args);
    HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart2, (uint8_t*)buff, strlen(buff),
                      HAL_MAX_DELAY);
    va_end(args);
}

void init() {
    UART_Printf("Ready!\r\n");
}




void loop() {
    HAL_StatusTypeDef res;
    int16_t signal[46876];
    int nsamples = sizeof(signal) / sizeof(signal[0]);
    UART_Printf("signal size = %d\r\n", sizeof(signal));
    UART_Printf("signal[0] = %d\r\n", sizeof(signal[0]));
    UART_Printf("nsamples = %d\r\n", nsamples);
    int i = 0;
    while(i < nsamples) {
        double t = ((double)i/2.0)/((double)nsamples);
        signal[i] = 32767*sin(100.0 * TAU * t); // left
        signal[i+1] = signal[i]; // right
        i += 2;
    }

    while(1) {
        res = HAL_I2S_Transmit(&hi2s2, (uint16_t*)signal, nsamples, HAL_MAX_DELAY);
        if(res != HAL_OK) {
            UART_Printf("I2S - ERROR, res = %d!\r\n", res);
            break;
        }
    }
}
/* USER CODE END 0 */

/**
  * @brief  The application entry point.
  * @retval int
  */
int main(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 1 */

  /* USER CODE END 1 */

  /* MCU Configuration--------------------------------------------------------*/

  /* Reset of all peripherals, Initializes the Flash interface and the Systick. */
  HAL_Init();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN Init */

  /* USER CODE END Init */

  /* Configure the system clock */
  SystemClock_Config();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN SysInit */

  /* USER CODE END SysInit */

  /* Initialize all configured peripherals */
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_USART2_UART_Init();
  MX_DMA_Init();
  MX_I2S2_Init();
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */

  /* USER CODE END 2 */

  /* Infinite loop */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */
  init();
  while (1)
  {
    /* USER CODE END WHILE */
      loop();
    /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */
  }
  /* USER CODE END 3 */
}

/**
  * @brief System Clock Configuration
  * @retval None
  */
void SystemClock_Config(void)
{
  RCC_OscInitTypeDef RCC_OscInitStruct = {0};
  RCC_ClkInitTypeDef RCC_ClkInitStruct = {0};

  /** Configure the main internal regulator output voltage
  */
  __HAL_RCC_PWR_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_PWR_VOLTAGESCALING_CONFIG(PWR_REGULATOR_VOLTAGE_SCALE1);
  /** Initializes the RCC Oscillators according to the specified parameters
  * in the RCC_OscInitTypeDef structure.
  */
  RCC_OscInitStruct.OscillatorType = RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSI;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSIState = RCC_HSI_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSICalibrationValue = RCC_HSICALIBRATION_DEFAULT;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLState = RCC_PLL_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLSource = RCC_PLLSOURCE_HSI;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLM = 16;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLN = 336;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLP = RCC_PLLP_DIV4;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLQ = 4;
  if (HAL_RCC_OscConfig(&RCC_OscInitStruct) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /** Initializes the CPU, AHB and APB buses clocks
  */
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.ClockType = RCC_CLOCKTYPE_HCLK|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_SYSCLK
                              |RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK1|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK2;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.SYSCLKSource = RCC_SYSCLKSOURCE_PLLCLK;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.AHBCLKDivider = RCC_SYSCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB1CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV2;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB2CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;

  if (HAL_RCC_ClockConfig(&RCC_ClkInitStruct, FLASH_LATENCY_2) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
}

/**
  * @brief I2S2 Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_I2S2_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN I2S2_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END I2S2_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE BEGIN I2S2_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END I2S2_Init 1 */
  hi2s2.Instance = SPI2;
  hi2s2.Init.Mode = I2S_MODE_MASTER_TX;
  hi2s2.Init.Standard = I2S_STANDARD_PHILIPS;
  hi2s2.Init.DataFormat = I2S_DATAFORMAT_32B;
  hi2s2.Init.MCLKOutput = I2S_MCLKOUTPUT_DISABLE;
  hi2s2.Init.AudioFreq = I2S_AUDIOFREQ_16K;
  hi2s2.Init.CPOL = I2S_CPOL_LOW;
  hi2s2.Init.ClockSource = I2S_CLOCK_PLL;
  hi2s2.Init.FullDuplexMode = I2S_FULLDUPLEXMODE_ENABLE;
  if (HAL_I2S_Init(&hi2s2) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN I2S2_Init 2 */

  /* USER CODE END I2S2_Init 2 */

}

/**
  * @brief USART2 Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_USART2_UART_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN USART2_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END USART2_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE BEGIN USART2_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END USART2_Init 1 */
  huart2.Instance = USART2;
  huart2.Init.BaudRate = 115200;
  huart2.Init.WordLength = UART_WORDLENGTH_8B;
  huart2.Init.StopBits = UART_STOPBITS_1;
  huart2.Init.Parity = UART_PARITY_NONE;
  huart2.Init.Mode = UART_MODE_TX_RX;
  huart2.Init.HwFlowCtl = UART_HWCONTROL_NONE;
  huart2.Init.OverSampling = UART_OVERSAMPLING_16;
  if (HAL_UART_Init(&huart2) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN USART2_Init 2 */

  /* USER CODE END USART2_Init 2 */

}

/**
  * Enable DMA controller clock
  */
static void MX_DMA_Init(void)
{

  /* DMA controller clock enable */
  __HAL_RCC_DMA1_CLK_ENABLE();

  /* DMA interrupt init */
  /* DMA1_Stream4_IRQn interrupt configuration */
  HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(DMA1_Stream4_IRQn, 0, 0);
  HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(DMA1_Stream4_IRQn);

}

/**
  * @brief GPIO Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void)
{
  GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct = {0};

  /* GPIO Ports Clock Enable */
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOC_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOH_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOB_CLK_ENABLE();

  /*Configure GPIO pin Output Level */
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(LD2_GPIO_Port, LD2_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);

  /*Configure GPIO pin : B1_Pin */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = B1_Pin;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_IT_FALLING;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(B1_GPIO_Port, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pin : LD2_Pin */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = LD2_Pin;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(LD2_GPIO_Port, &GPIO_InitStruct);

}

/* USER CODE BEGIN 4 */

/* USER CODE END 4 */

/**
  * @brief  This function is executed in case of error occurrence.
  * @retval None
  */
void Error_Handler(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN Error_Handler_Debug */
  /* User can add his own implementation to report the HAL error return state */
  __disable_irq();
  while (1)
  {
  }
  /* USER CODE END Error_Handler_Debug */
}

#ifdef  USE_FULL_ASSERT
/**
  * @brief  Reports the name of the source file and the source line number
  *         where the assert_param error has occurred.
  * @param  file: pointer to the source file name
  * @param  line: assert_param error line source number
  * @retval None
  */
void assert_failed(uint8_t *file, uint32_t line)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 6 */
  /* User can add his own implementation to report the file name and line number,
     ex: printf("Wrong parameters value: file %s on line %d\r\n", file, line) */
  /* USER CODE END 6 */
}
#endif /* USE_FULL_ASSERT */

First thing I mentioned, it's really quiet, though I don't know if this is actually a problem. Second, is there's a popping noise on a very regular basis.
I left the gain on the amp floating, which should give it a 9dB gain. I also was running it on 3.3V, so that could be affecting volume. I also realized I had a mismatch in how my I2S is set up relative to the example, specifically the data format, audio frequency and full duplex mode.
I think the problem is in the frequency mismatch and the sine wave setup, but I can't fully grasp it to make the adjustments. I feel like I'm almost there but need a nudge in the right direction.

Please ask a specific question. You don't have a question at the moment.

signal[46876] allocates 94 kB on the stack, this is very unusual. Check if this is valid for this MCU context. You may want to add the "static" attribute to move the buffer to a safe place.

The MAX98357A typically expects a 16-bit data format, which means that if your MCU is transmitting 32-bit data.You have to adjust the I2S data format to 16-bit (I2S_DATAFORMAT_16B) by modifying the MX_I2S2_Init function. Here is how you can modify the function.
static void MX_I2S2_Init(void)
{
  hi2s2.Instance = SPI2;
  hi2s2.Init.Mode = I2S_MODE_MASTER_TX;
  hi2s2.Init.Standard = I2S_STANDARD_PHILIPS;
  hi2s2.Init.DataFormat = I2S_DATAFORMAT_16B;
  hi2s2.Init.MCLKOutput = I2S_MCLKOUTPUT_DISABLE;
  hi2s2.Init.AudioFreq = I2S_AUDIOFREQ_48K;
  hi2s2.Init.CPOL = I2S_CPOL_LOW;
  hi2s2.Init.ClockSource = I2S_CLOCK_PLL;
  hi2s2.Init.FullDuplexMode = I2S_FULLDUPLEXMODE_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_I2S_Init(&hi2s2) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
}

You can also try other ICS like TPA3255 to make your amplifier:
https://www.pcbway.com/project/shareproject/STEREO_AMPLIFIER_TPA3255_CLASS_D_86b72a3a.html

I'll keep that in mind. I can't get new parts to try for a while, so I'll have to stick with the MAX98357A for now. Would the data format account for the popping or how quiet the speaker is?

Would that be 16 bit data in 16 bit frames?
